# Changing RAID1 HDDs (Dell PowerEdge R430) to another identical server

Tags: dell-poweredge, raid1

I'm new with server configuration and infrastructure.

If I have two identical servers (PowerEdge R430), one for spare without HDDs  (call it S1), and another online with the HDDs (S2). If I remove the HDDs from S2 and place it on S1, will it work without the need to configure?

I've tried clonning one HDD (with macrium reflect) and then startup in a lab server with only the clonned HDD, but it show no virtual disk.

I need this, because the group responsible for fix the issue in case of emergency has no knowledge about software, only hardware, and the fix need to be fast (Industrial Automation maintenance team). So now we have the backup needed with Virtual Machine but they want to remove the VM's because they don't know how to work with it.

Comment: it only works when they have the same raid controller and you need to sump the raid configuration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most Dell RAID controllers (PERC) allow importing an array from the disks:  shut down source server, move disks over to destination server (in same cage order), power up server, import disks, boot. Also, depending on the OS setup (e.g. UEFI secure boot), manual selection of the boot volume may be required.

Both servers should have the same RAID controller models and firmware versions. More or less, this mandates keeping the backup server up to date, just like a production server.

> the group responsible for fix the issue in case of emergency has no knowledge about software, only hardware, and the fix need to be fast

This is a major problem. Chances are high that such a switchover recovery is going to fail even if it is well planned. You could lower the risk only by proper and *regular* training and *testing*. With no qualified person on-site, you should prepare for fully remote operation/maintenance.

I'd suggest buying another set of disks and synchronizing S1 and S2 automatically (permanently/hourly/daily). Depending on your setup, licensing and infrastructure, you should consider an automatic or semi-automatic failover instead of a manual - and error-prone - procedure. Running a virtual machine is a good first step!